# How to allow user to Tap header to open on ExpansionPanel

Tags: flutter, dart

I have built a help / FAQ screen within my flutter app. Using expansion tile I have created the UI but I am having issues with tapping the header.

I'm wanting to allow the user to tap the header to open that tile. Currently, the user has to tap the arrow to open.

I have added "canTapOnHeader: true," but that does not seem to work. I've searched Stackoverflow but still had no luck

Any help would be great!

```
ExpansionPanel(
                headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
                  return Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                          child: Text(
                            itemData[index].headerItem,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                              fontSize: 17,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
                body: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 30),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image.asset(
                        itemData[index].img,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                      Divider(
                          thickness: 3.0,
                          height: 3.0,
                          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                          indent: 10,
                          endIndent: 300),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, top: 10),
                        child: Text(
                          itemData[index].description,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                            fontSize: 15,
                            height: 1.3,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                canTapOnHeader: true,
                isExpanded: itemData[index].expanded,
              )
            ],
            expansionCallback: (int item, bool status) {
              setState(() {
                itemData[index].expanded = !itemData[index].expanded;
              });
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
);}




List<ItemModel> itemData = <ItemModel>[
    ItemModel(
      headerItem: 'This is a header question?',
      description:
          "This is the description for the question.",
      img: 'assets/images/typingtextgiphy.gif',
    ),
  ];
}

class ItemModel {
  bool expanded;
  String headerItem;
  String description;
  String img;

  ItemModel({
    this.expanded: false,
    this.headerItem,
    this.description,
    this.img,
  });
}
```

Comment: did you fixed this problem? @user16034511

Comment: Yes, I've just posted the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Managed to find the solution for this. Here's the code, can copy and paste

```
class _HelpPanelState extends State<HelpPanel> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MediaQuery(
      data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          leading: BackButton(
            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          ),
          title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.tutorial,
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary)),
          elevation: 0.0,
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 3,
                    shape: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 0.0, left: 15.0, right: 15.0, bottom: 0.0),
                      child: ExpansionTile(
                        title: Text(
                         "QUESTION",
                          style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                            textStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                              letterSpacing: 0.4,
                            ),
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        ),
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                            ),
                            child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                              child: Image(
                                image: AssetImage(
                                  'assets/images/typingautoverse.gif',
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 5),
                          Padding(
                            padding:
                                const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, bottom: 10),
                            child: Text(
                         "ANSWER",
                              style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                textStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                  letterSpacing: 0.4,
                                  height: 1.3,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 3,
                    shape: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 0.0, left: 15.0, right: 15.0, bottom: 0.0),
                      child: ExpansionTile(
                        title: Text(
                         "QUESTION",
                          style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                            textStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                              letterSpacing: 0.4,
                            ),
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        ),
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding:
                                const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, bottom: 10),
                            child: Text(
                             "ANSWER"
                              style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                textStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                  letterSpacing: 0.4,
                                  height: 1.3,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```